# how to store user friends using HWIOAuthBundle

Tags: api, symfony, fosuserbundle, hwioauthbundle

how to store user friends using HWIOAuthBundle into database i already configure it with fosBundle and i can store user information into DB but i don't know how to store the friends list

```
 facebook:
            type: facebook
            client_id: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            client_secret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            scope: "email,public_profile,manage_pages,publish_actions,user_friends,user_groups,user_likes"
```